# How to solve the integral of $\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \int_{0} ^{\cos\theta} \sqrt{12r^6 \sin^2 (2\theta)}$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

So what I am trying to do is to find the surface area over a disc inside a sphere. The sphere is given by: $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$ and the disc: $(x-(\frac{1}{2}))^2 +y^2 \le \frac{1}{4}$

I found the boundaries to be $\frac{-\pi}{2} \le \theta\le \frac{\pi}{2}$ and $0\le r \le cos\theta $

So now I am trying to solve $ \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \int_{0} ^{\cos\theta} dS$

Where $dS = \left\lvert \frac{d\mathbf{R}}{dr} \times \frac{d\mathbf{R}}{d\theta} \right\rvert$

I've parameterized the sphere as
$ x=r cos(\theta) , y = r sin(\theta) and z=\sqrt{1-r^2}$

Getting $ \mathbf{R}$ = (($r cos(\theta)^2)$,($r sin(\theta)^2)$,($1-r^2$))

Solving $\frac{d\mathbf{R}}{dr}$ gives me $(2rcos^2 \theta, 2rsin^2 \theta, -2r)$ and $\frac{d\mathbf{R}}{d\theta}$ gives me $(-r^2 sin(2\theta),(r^2 sin(2\theta),0)$

Soving $dS$ gets me $\sqrt{12r^6 \sin^2 (2\theta)}$

So now I am struggling to find a way to calculate the integral of: $\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \int_{0} ^{\cos\theta} \sqrt{12r^6 \sin^2(2\theta)} dr d\theta $

Comment: You're missing }

Comment: Don't you think that a d$\theta$d$r$ would be welcome ?

Comment: and you could write \pi to get $\pi$

Comment: I am very sorry for the inconvenience, really tired and new to Math Jax, thanks for the corrections

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: the integrand is even, so I would integrate $\theta$ from $0$ to $\pi/2$. This way everything under the square root is a positive quantity, so the integral becomes $$2\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin\theta d\theta\int_0^{\cos\theta}dr\sqrt{12}r^3$$ 
Once you integrate over $r$, you will get an expression in terms of $\cos\theta$. Make the substitution $u=\cos\theta$, with $du=-\sin\theta d\theta$. The limits of integration become $\cos 0=1$ (lower limit) and $\cos\frac \pi2=0$ (upper limit). Note that changing the order of limits means an extra minus sign, that will cancel the one from $du$.

Comment: I am sorry if this is a stupid question, but I don't follow/understand the first step, what's happening there?

Comment: If $f(x)=f(-x)$, an integral $\int_{-a}^af(x)dx$ can be written as $\int_{-a}^0f(x)dx+\int_{0}^af(x)dx=-\int_0^{-a}f(x)dx+\int_{0}^af(x)dx$. Now changing the variable in the first integral from $x$ to $-x$ you get  $-\int_0^{-a}f(x)dx+\int_{0}^af(x)dx=\int_{0}^af(x)dx+\int_{0}^af(x)dx=2\int_{0}^af(x)dx$.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

Mathematica says

```
Integrate[Sqrt[12*r^6*Sin[t]^2], {t, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, {r, 0, Cos[t]}]
```

$$\frac{\sqrt{3}}{5} $$

```
NIntegrate[Sqrt[12*r^6*Sin[t]^2], {t, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, {r, 0, Cos[t]}]
```

$$0.34641 $$

Addition. The Mathematica answer to the edited by OP question is

```
Integrate[r^3*Sqrt[12*Sin[2*t]^2], {t, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, {r, 0, Cos[t]}]
```

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} $

Comment: Looking back it should be $\sqrt{12r^6 \sin^2 (2\theta)}$ , however either way I am looking for a way to solve this by hand

Comment: @LostCoder: I added the answer to the question edited by you.